# Why does variable is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following function:

```
    $.getJSON(
                    'getTerminalinsideCircle.json',
                    {
                        centerLatitude: adressMarker.getPosition().lat(),
                        centerLongitude:adressMarker.getPosition().lng(),
                        radius :radius/1000

                    }, function (data) {
                          $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                   ....
                          }
                        )
                    }
            )
```

I wanted ro refactor it and rewrite it so:

```
$.getJSON(
                'getTerminalinsideCircle.json',
                {
                    centerLatitude: adressMarker.getPosition().lat(),
                    centerLongitude: adressMarker.getPosition().lng(),
                    radius: radius / 1000

                }, renderTerminalOnMap(data)
        )
        function renderTerminalOnMap(data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                       ...
                    }
            )
        }
```

but in console I see that `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

How to refactor it right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `renderTerminalOnMap` instead of `renderTerminalOnMap(data)` as callback.

By writing `renderTerminalOnMap(data)` you actually immediately call the function with the `data` parameter, which is an `undefined` variable, and set the `return value` of that function as the callback.

When you pass functions as callbacks you just have to pass the function name, the parameters will be transmitted by the `getJSON` function itself.

```
        $.getJSON(
                'getTerminalinsideCircle.json',
                {
                    centerLatitude: adressMarker.getPosition().lat(),
                    centerLongitude: adressMarker.getPosition().lng(),
                    radius: radius / 1000

                }, renderTerminalOnMap
        );

        function renderTerminalOnMap(data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                       ...
                    }
            )
        }
```